# Changing the color of dot depending from value on Morris js graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, morris.js

Im rendering graph by morris js. Im using data from mysql database by JSON.

Everything works fine, but I would like to add one more feature to the graph. (change dot color if there is something in buy action).

My JSON:

> [{"longdate":"2014-08-20
>   18:20:01","price":"1620","action":"**buy**"},{"longdate":"2014-08-20
>   18:40:01","price":"1640","action":""},{"longdate":"2014-08-20
>   19:00:01","price":"1620","action":""}]

So I would like to change dot color for values with buy action.

My code for graph:

```
$.getJSON('results.json', function(day_data) {

Morris.Line({
  element: 'graph',
  data: day_data,
  xkey: 'longdate',
  ykeys: ['price'], 
  labels: ['Cena'],
  lineColors: lineColor,
  pointSize: 0,
  hoverCallback: function(index, options, content) { 
 var date = "<b><font color='black'>Data: "+day_data[index]['longdate']+"</font></b><br>";
     var param1 = "<font color='"+lineColor[0]+"'>Cena - "+day_data[index]['price']+"</font><br>";
     return date+param1;
  },
  xLabelFormat : function (x) {
   return changeDateFormat(x);
  }

  /*My TRIAL
if(action == 'buy'){
pointSize: 4,
lineColors: green,
}
 */ 

});
});
```

So my code doesnt work, how can I make this working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing color depending on value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426445/changing-color-depending-on-value)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [documentation for the line chart](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html), this library is not capable of doing what you are asking "out of the box" (meaning, without modification).

You could always fork the [github project](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js) and add this capability. If you are not interested or able to do that, then you'll probably need to choose a different charting library.